# Error while running the GWT developer mode

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, gwt, vaadin7

While starting my application in the GWT dev mode from Intellij. I got the following error:-

```
 ERROR: Failed to create an instance of 'com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection' via deferred binding 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.createImpl(GWT.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:65)
    at com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader.get(ConnectorBundleLoader.java:76)
    at com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection.<init>(ApplicationConnection.java:534)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:493)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.createImpl(GWT.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConfiguration$1.execute(ApplicationConfiguration.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:341)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:589)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:551)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost
```

I understands from the error that i missed to inherit any module. But in which module does this "com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection" comes as it's class of vaadin itself.
I'm using vaadin 7.4.6 version
`<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />` is already inherited.

Comment: Hmm `Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost`

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Hi, do you have idea about it, please? There is more logs after this line i didn't pasted whole here.

Comment: Remote connection lost means either your browser/tab get closed or server stops

Comment: but it complains about 'com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection' class saying you forget to inherit any module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to solve this issue and sharing it here, it might be helpful for others.

- Removed all old compiled widget sets from the target
- Recompile the the whole full project again

And then I found, it starts working fine.